# Read only a specific value in LC_Type1 Class Table for MCD12Q1.006 MODIS Land Cover Type Yearly Global 500m

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, java, modis

I have defined a specific area to look at but now I want to only read the data for the water.

MCD12Q1.006 MODIS Land Cover Type Yearly Global 500m has a LC_Type1 Class Table and I only want to read value 17 because it has the water. How can I do this?

```
var Landcover = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD12Q1"); //terra
  var collectionTerra = Landcover
  .filterBounds(Lake_Sup)
  .filterDate('2014-07-01', '2014-08-31');

  var clip1 = function(images) {
    return images.clip(LakeSP);
  }
```

Comment: Can you post a more complete script? Is clip1 supposed to do something? It's never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not *exactly* sure what you're looking for, but if it is to pare down the landcover layer to only water/not water, then you can do something like the following, which selects only the `LC_Type1` band, loops through each image in the image collection and creates a boolean output for whether or not the band value equals `17`.

```
var Landcover = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD12Q1");
var collectionTerra = Landcover
.filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate('2010-07-01', '2014-08-31')
.select(['LC_Type1'])
.map(function(image) {
  return image.eq(17)
});

Map.addLayer(collectionTerra)
```

[image]